# how to create rails 3 custom exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am creating some custom exceptions as follows

lib/exceptions.rb

```
module Exceptions
  class MemberOverFlow < StandardError
  end
  rescue_from MemberOverFlow do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```

I use to raise the exception like this.

```
raise Exception::MemberOverFlow"member count overflow"
```

It giving the following error

```
NoMethodError in MembersController#create

undefined method `MemberOverFlow' for Exception:Class
```

can anyone tell me what is problem

thanks

Comment: Your module name is Exceptions and you are using `Exception::`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you require the module in the controller where you are trying to raise the exception?

`require "exception" #or wherever you have placed the module file`

Use:
`raise Exception::MemberOverFlow.new("member count overflow")`

and if it still does not work, try changing the name of the module "Exception" because Exception is an existing exception class defined in Ruby.

Comment: I at first missed your comment on the original question re. a possible typo. If it's not a typo, because his module is named `Exceptions` (plural), it must be called as `raise Exceptions::MemberOverFlow.new("member count overflow")`. Also, he specifies that the file name is `lib/exceptions.rb`, so the require statement must also be plural:  `require "exceptions"`.

Answer (score 9):

No one specifically called out what was wrong in the original post.  The following:

```
raise Exceptions::MemberOverFlow"member count overflow"
```

is treating `MemberOverFlow` as a METHOD and not the `class` that it is.  You need to call the `new` method on your `MemberOverFlow` class, which is what amit_saxena's answer points out.

That answer solves the problem, but I just felt it was worth pointing out what you were doing syntactically so that if you ever had a similar problem in the future you would know what was going on.

Answer (score 5):

The contents of your lib directory are not automatically loaded in rails 3, you need to specify them like so in config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Perhaps you have not done that?